# How can I view or download the file system of a Wordpress site hosted with AWS?

Tags: web-hosting, ftp, amazon-aws

I am trying to revamp a website for a non-profit and have not used AWS prior. The original website I'm trying to copy/download is hosted on AWS, and I was planning on moving it to hosting I already control elsewhere. I thought I would be able to find a way to FTP into AWS' web hosting and have the whole Wordpress file system downloaded in a few minutes (I really just need the pictures and content; the originals are no longer available as far as I can tell, and I don't need to replicate the sight plugin-for-plugin).

Unfortunately, AWS Console is clogged with dozens of uninformative product names and no clear path even to see an in-browser listing of the hosted files.

Can anyone tell me how to FTP into AWS or point me to where these tool are hiding in AWS console?

Comment: Unfirtunately this is off-topic. That aside - why? Why not just get a Wordpress plugin and do a backup from wuthin Wirdpress (Updraft, Backupbuddy spring to mind). It us unlikely you can do what yoy want vua the AWS console - it is fir controlling hardware and startup - it knows block devices (drives) not files...

Comment: Alternatives could include using scp/sftp as this allows file access and is based  on the ssh protocol used on most vm's, or to install an FTP server (you may need to adjust the AWS  firewall settings to allow this), or to add some kind if file explorer/cms web interface.

Comment: Why? Because most of the stuff you're talking about doesn't mean much to me. The last website I made for money was in 1995, but I still use FTP on a regular basis.

Comment: That said, I will try your backup plugin idea. Thank you.

Comment: You might need to know that a) Wordpress keeps the web page text in a MySQL database, not file system, b) The images are generally in (DocumentRoot)/wp-content/uploads and c) AWS is a virtual machine control panel, not a web hosting control panel.  Its entirely common to run CPanel or equivalent on an AWS virtual machine (ec2) instance - in which case you want the control panel, not aws login to do the kind of things you are trying to do - although as I said, it can also be achieved within Wordpress by using appropriate plugins.

Comment: Unfortunately, Wordpress requests FTP credentials when you try to install any plugins. This is fun.

Comment: This might be a better fit for Superuser.com or Wordpress.com.  Wordpress has lots of options for installing plugins - and the FTP one is not actually that common. This is likely due to a permissions issue, but it could also be specified in (documentroot)/wp-config.php - The reality though is that to fix this you will likely either need the credentials to log in via SSH (in which case you may be able to use sftp or scp)  or you need someone with the skills to reset this in AWS or pull the data off the system for you - this requires a good knowledge of Linux and is likely out of your league.

Comment: If, as your question implies, you are going to rebuild the site, have you considered simply spidering the site to capture the images/content?  This does not require any special access.

Answer (score 1):

AWS is a very large collection of web services that offer multiple ways to host a WordPress website.

- An EC2 instance (virtual private server) running WordPress and the database
- An EC2 instance with a separate managed database hosted in relation database service (RDS).
- Same as above, but all created through Lightsail
- Multiple EC2 instances behind a load balancer with an RDS database and a shared S3 bucket for files
- Same as above but using elastic file system (EFS) for shared files
- Containerized WordPress instances running on ECS or EKS with files in EFS or S3 with the database in RDS.

I would suggest checking your account's AWS Billing Dashboard to figure out what services you are using.   The method you will need to use to copy everything is going to be dependent on what services are running.

- EC2: Default access to EC2 instances is through SSH.  You'll need to get the keys from the person that created the instance.  If you can't get the keys, you'll have to go through a [snapshot and recovery process](https://ehikioya.com/locked-aws-ec2-regain-access/).
- RDS: To dump an MySQL database you would [typically use mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217299/how-to-export-database-from-amazon-rds-mysql-instance-to-local-instance) either from an EC2 instance or from a remote box configured with access.  There are other options though, for example you could [configure it to replicate to an external database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html) or [export a snapshot to s3 and dowload it from there](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html)
- S3: If your data is in an S3 bucket, you probably want to [sync the entire bucket to your local machine](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/download-entire-s3-bucket).

Bottom line, AWS is **way** more complicated than your average shared hosting account.  There is no one-size-fits-all way to use AWS and as a result there can be no simple or comprehensive instructions for exporting a WordPress site from it.